# How to design an offset cancellation circuit for strongARM latch?

Tags: comparator, offset

I have been working on a strongARM latch and I wanted to add a subsystem for elimination of  the offset. Circuit diagram is attached with this question. For simulation purpose I have added an external voltage source to model the offset. I have been working on different ideas but none of them worked. The output is measured between Vx & Vy and the input is given at Vin+ & Vin-.

NOTE: The offset could be due to transistor mismatch or some other reason. To model that  a small voltage is placed (voltage is not added , it signifies the offset )

[image]

Comment: A perfect solution is basically impossible and this is a very broad question. Explain the ideas you've tried so far and how they failed, so we don't just waste time repeating the same old ground like matching transistors, adding external trim, laser trimmed resistors, etc. Also add your constroints on max acceptable offset, and bandwidth.

Comment: Looking at all your questions sofar leads me to conclude that you need to follow a course on **analog circuit / IC design**. Also: if you want a low offset input, **this circuit is pretty bad** because the **load** of the diff. pair (M1, M2) isn't symmetrical. Yes the circuit is symmetrical but when in use, the voltages at P and Q are not the same. For a low offset input, you need a completely symmetrical circuit (you have that) but also identical operating conditions for the transistors (you do not have that).

Comment: I was trying to add a capacitor and short the input . My idea was that this capacitor gets charged to a magnitude equal to Voffset. But these work only for single ended output. For this circuit , it did not work. @user_1818839

Comment: That is exactly what I am trying. I currently does not have a strong base , so I am parallelly learning the basics and doing the simulation. Do you have any course in specific that I could learn?                                                                                                        And regarding this question , my aim is to reduce the offset by adding some extra circuit.

Comment: *my aim is to reduce the offset by adding some extra circuit* So you're of the design approach of "only fixing things by making them more complex" while I am from the design approach of "understanding **WHY** the problem exists and then tackle the root cause" (which is straightforward for this circuit: add some current mirrors).

Comment: I think there is a communication gap. My situation is like this, there is a 10mV offset(I assumed offset will be in a range of -10mV to +10mV)  in my circuit for some reason, while manufacturing it. Lets assume it be some unequal parasitic capacitance or sizing mismatch or something. This is a simulation and this will be perfect but then while manufacturing it there is a possibility of mismatch right? so i thought adding a voltage source to model that offset and then try to remove it.Also  this offset could be any value in that range.  @Bimpelrekkie

Comment: Did you get what I meant? The offset is present is my assumption , its not like I want to know why that offset is present. My aim is to make a circuit to cancel the offset.@Bimpelrekkie

Comment: @HariKrishna Um, the circuit to cancel the offset is another voltage source connected in series with either Vin1 or Vin2 :) See, adding voltage sources to model offset is a game that's easy to exploit, and makes it easy to fool yourself into thinking that you got a solution. Recall that real offset is temperature-dependent. Your fake offset will make actual offset cancellation techniques not work (or work poorly) as soon as you do a temperature sweep in the simulation (as you should!).

Answer (score 1):

Your model is incorrect. The offset voltage source, as you've modeled, is an actual input you're providing. In reality, offsets result from the parameter spread and non-ideal behavior of the transistors making up the device.

So, "fixing" the offset that is created by the inherent properties of the real devices used, requires to have a **model where the circuit itself exhibits offset as an inherent property of the elements used**. Why? Because the transistors that cause the offset do so largely due to the way they are operated in this circuit, and you would go a long way to operate them in a way that minimizes this effect. Additional offset cancellation by current or charge injection is then a secondary correction, of a smaller magnitude.

1. Set up your SPICE simulation so that the instantiated device offsets follow a distribution typical for the process. Each instantiation should give you slightly different offset that way.
2. Apply offset minimization techniques that take this into account, i.e. using actual, non-ideal devices in the process of your choice.

At first glance, all you need is a current mirror in the load of M1 and M2. Look at, for example, [this patent](https://patents.google.com/patent/US8598914B2/en) for ideas.

Programmable capacitors are used in actual StrongARM latch implementations for the purpose of offset cancellation - look at, for example, [this paper](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Epister/140sp17/resources/StrongArm_BR2015.pdf). If that's what you did, then perhaps you should re-read how it's done, and *ask specific questions, showing your actual implementation*.